# An open-source CodeIgniter based e-commerce app that I can contribute to?

Tags: php, codeigniter, open-source, e-commerce

I'd like to get involved in open source projects to try and get rid of the n00b-hood which seems to cling to me like a gecko to flypaper.

It seems that there are no open source e-commerce solutions built on codeigniter - a search on Google, a search on Github, and a search on Stackoverflow all brought out 0 coherent results.

If anybody knows of such a project, please let me know, so I can start contributing my part to the development - that is the only way i'll ever improve, and i'm sure any mentor would like a little help on their pet project...

Besides, I think Oscommerce (and any of it's numerous cousins) seems a bit immature in it's approach even to a non-ninja like me, and magento is totally undemocratic with it's insistence of innoDB requirement and the impossible complexity of the code architecture.

Comment: before i do that, i want to make sure that somebody else hasn't already... besides, one needs to be a wielder of mighty skill to be proud enough to start their own opensource project. i am no more than a grasshopper - maybe that would be too arrogant a step to take?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far I have only found 2 e-commerce solutions that utilise codeigniter.

1. Total Shop UK - Was announced in [this thread](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/153137/)
2. Community Cart - [recently updated to v2.01](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Community_Cart/)

E-commerce in code-igniter has been talked about a lot. It baffles me why so few have developed apps in this area.

My personal opinion is that there is definitely an opportunity to create a slick e-commerce app using code-igniter now that CI 2.0 is finally here!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions - Total Shop UK is ANTI-forking. Check this out: http://www.totalshopuk.com/license

I'm trying out Community Cart right now though. Might just start contributing to it :)

Answer (score 2):

There's also GoCart, which is built on CodeIgniter: http://gocartdv.com/.

Answer (score 0):

I would check out [OpenCart](http://www.opencart.com/) - it's not a codeigniter system but it *is* based on a MVC model and the source is very organized. You can control most of the templates, it has built in localization and multiple taxes etc..

Comment: Thanks for the head's up... I've been trying to install and try this baby out back since you posted this answer, but dang it, I just don't find the time! :)

Comment: Oh my god, I can't thank you enough for suggesting OpenCart. Using OsCommerce for a long time convinced me that the world is usually full of dark, unintuitive ecommerce systems that are very hard to customize for the developer and downright ugly for a non-technical admin to manage.

I'm very happy with the system thanks :)

Comment: You are welcome. I hope it works out for you.